# Can't call method "text" without a package or object reference

Tags: perl

The following is my code

```
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple;
use WWW::Mechanize;
use WWW::Mechanize::Link;


my $mech = new  WWW::Mechanize();
my $link = new  WWW::Mechanize::Link();

my $file = 'source1.txt';
my $filename = 'links2.txt';

open(my $fh, '>', $filename) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
open my $info, $file or die "Could not open $file: $!";

while( my $line = <$info>)  {
 $link = grep(/<a.*href=.*>/,$line);
   print $fh $link->text;

}
close $fh;
```

when I try to run this I get the error
Can't call method "text" without a package or object reference.

Comment: *Always* `use strict;`!

Comment: `grep` doesn’t do what you think it does, and you’re [parsing HTML with regex, which is a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/418066). The immediate error, however, is with `$link->text`; consider what `$link` is here.

Comment: Why do you have LWP::Simple and WWW::Mechanize and use neither?

Answer (score 5):

In scalar context, `grep` returns the number of items in the list that "match" the criterion. So, because there is only one item in your list, your statement

```
$link = grep( /<a.*href=.*>/, $line )
```

will set `$link` to either 1 or 0 according to whether `$line` matches the regex `/<a.*href=.*>/`

Then you have

```
print $fh $link->text
```

which calls either `1->text` or `0-text`, neither of which make sense